# Mac compatible Web-Development Tools

Tags: mac, web-development

I'm looking for any Mac compatibile development tools that are tried and tested.

I'm quite sick of my MySQL query browser crashing... And i'm sure there is probably better software out there anyways...

At the moment my focus is dedicated to application development using PHP/MySQL/Ajax. (although, I will be learning ActionScript/Flex shortly).

Here are the apps I regularly use and a general idea of the environment I work in:

```
Hosting -
   localhost: Mamp
   Production: Amazon EC2

IDE -
   Coda: PHP/Mysql/Javascript

Mysql -
   PHPMyAdmin
   MySQL query browser

FTP -
   Coda
   FileZilla

X11 is used for connecting to my production environment
```

I am mainly looking for...

```
-tools that will help me better manage (create, edit... whatever) databases.
-Version control.  This is huge as I'm working with a team of three other developers (we reeeeeeaaally need to standardize our environments..)
```

Although any cool little tools to make my job easier are always a plus!

I am unable to insert more than one link as I'm not rated on this forum.

Answer (score 2):

I use the following extensively:

[**TextMate**](http://macromates.com/) is a fast and easy to pick up text editor that handles every syntax I've ever used (PHP, MySQL, Perl, Ruby, Python, Java, CSS, and more). With bundles and keyboard shortcuts it greatly speeds up the time it takes to code.

[**Cornerstone**](http://www.zennaware.com/) or [**SmartCVS**](http://www.syntevo.com/smartcvs/index.html) for SVN / CVS respectively.

[**Transmit**](http://www.panic.com/transmit/) for FTP. Tight Mac OSX integration and good speeds make this one a winner.

[**CoRD**](http://cord.sourceforge.net/) for remote desktop on IIS boxes.

[**Terminal**](http://macapper.com/2007/03/08/the-terminal-an-introduction/) for ssh and anything I can't do with another program in including [tailing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_%28Unix%29) logs and [grep](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ugrep.htm).

[**Changes**](http://connectedflow.com/changes/) for file diff / merge.

[**Sequel Pro**](http://www.sequelpro.com/) if I don't want to use [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) for database manipulation.

For version control I recommend SVN over CVS. It's smarter, faster, less prone to errors and conflicts, and easier to understand for the beginner. There are a variety of SVN hosts but I find [Slik SVN](http://www.sliksvn.com/) to be a great free host.

Comment: I used textmate... I like Coda better for its project management functionality.  I'll definitely check out the others (x11 == terminal)

Comment: Code is better in a "this is your project" sense, but it tries to cram too much stuff in there at once. It has a lackluster editor, and the rest of the features just fell short for me. The "Publish" feature was the only thing I missed moving to TextMate full time.

Comment: wow. This is the EXACT same list I use with the exception of Cornerstone and SmartCVS (I use git).

Comment: Never tried GIT, how is it?

Answer (score 2):

DON'T FORGIT GIT.

/me ducks

http://git-scm.com/

Answer (score 1):

Another vote for Sequel Pro for MySQL stuff. For SVN, I can recommend [Versions](http://versionsapp.com/). It's not free, but it makes SVN a breeze to use and works nicely along side Coda.

Comment: I've only just opened sequel pro and I already love it =)

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL browsing I highly recommend [Navicat](https://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat-for-mysql). I do extensive PHP/MySQL development and I couldn't live without it.