# Pictures display oddly in Dreamweaver but look fine in a broswer

Tags: firefox, images, dreamweaver

For some odd reason whenever I put a picture into Dreamweaver it screws up the color when I editing it in Dreamweaver but when I open the page up in Firefox it looks fine. Anyone know what's going on?

Dreamweaver CS4:

[image]

Firefox:

[image]

Comment: That image server seem to be a bit shaky.

Answer (score 1):

Dreamweaver is highlighting placed or positioned objects in the web page. Either that or you've found a way to invert the colors.

Comment: By highlighting do you mean that I have it selected? I haven't been messing around with any of the preferences.

Comment: I mean that Dreamweaver will put visual "placeholder" objects on screen for hidden objects, and sometimes it will either shade or outline other objects like images, links, positioned divs. Part of the reason I don't use Dreamweaver for web development.

Comment: Do you know any good alternatives to Dreamweaver that you use?

Comment: I'll throw in a vote for KompoZer http://www.kompozer.net/

Comment: TextMate and your favorite browser. Check http://superuser.com/questions/104819/mac-compatible-web-development-tools/104821#104821 for more programs.

Answer (score 1):

Dreamweaver is useful for visual editing, but the visual output is not accurate. It's better to use a web browser to make sure.

Comment: It was working perfectly fine before. I usually preview my work in the browser when I'm done.

Comment: The browser, or all the browsers?